# Flutter, image not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

I really tried everything. No indentation problem with `pubspec.yaml`, no mistake in the name...

Here's my code :

```dart
return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('img/logo.png'),
              ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: _createTextFormField(loginEmailController, Icons.alternate_email, "Email Adress", false, TextInputType.emailAddress),
          ),
          Container(
            child: _createTextFormField(loginPasswordController, Icons.lock, "Password", true, TextInputType.text),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: loginButton
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

and my `pubspec.yaml` :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/img/logo.png
```

and finaly my folder organization :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: so why `AssetImage('img/logo.png')` and not `AssetImage('lib/assets/img/logo.png')`?

Comment: Ok so I actually had to re-write the entire path. I didn't know that. Thank you !

Comment: otherwise how the framework could know that `img/logo.png` is really `lib/assets/img/logo.png`?

Comment: How to change the topic to 'resolved' ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: ...]

Put assets directory like in the image.

After that `AssetImage('assets/logo.png')`

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried everything, don't forget to re-write the entire path when you're using an image.